# Is it possible to write a Mercurial to extend standard commands?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I have been looking into writing an extension for Mercurial and have found [this documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WritingExtensions).

From what I can see, you can create new commands within the Mercurial environment but what I was hoping to achieve however, was to override an existing command like the `commit` command. My override would contain logic and if it passes it would then call the original `commit` super function.

Is it possible to extend the functionality of pre-existing Mercurial commands?

Thanks

Comment: Can you implement your override as a precommit hook instead?

Comment: From what I can tell, hooks are only attached to repositories, rather than computers/accounts/clients. Is this the case?

Comment: You can install a hook for the whole system - see the different hgrc locations here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/hgrc . There's a good chapter on hooks here http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html

Comment: I'd like to emphasize Sigve Kolbeinson's comment: make use of the system-wide hooks. It's common practise to utilize them on servers e.g. for CI purposes. But also on desktops to run certain checkes prior to commit or push